# Visual Studio Intellisense Does Not Recognize System.Transactions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I've been trying to add "System.Transactions" to my project which I did it successfully but the Intellisense does not recognize it and I can't load any methods. Besides, VS warns me that such a namespace does not exist.

But I am **ABLE** to build and run the project.

Any idea?
[image]

Comment: Try doing a clean and rebuild of your project.  If that doesn't work, close your project and reopen it.  If that doesn't work, close and reopen Visual Studio and reopen your project.

Comment: @AHBagheri, Remove the reference, and then re-add it again with going to References ->add System.Transactions, and then make sure on the properties, set "Copy Local =True", view the result again.

Comment: @AHBagheri, If you get any latest information in your side, feel free to share it here.